# Is it possible to specify localhost url in gmail contextual gadget - manifest file

Tags: google-apps-script, manifest, google-apps-marketplace, google-gadget, gmail-contextual-gadgets

```
< Extension id="Demo Gadget" type="gadget" >
    < Name > Gmail contextual gadget < /Name >
    < Url > http://54.201.166.244:8080/xmlproject/Gadget.xml < /Url >
< Container name="mail" />
```

Is it possible to specify localhost url in url tag that refer to `gadget.xml` from gmail contextual gadget manifest file.

Comment: You could use a local tunnel solution in order to bypass it for your development. Few options: https://localtunnel.me/ or https://ngrok.com/

Answer (score 0):

No. As per the [instructions](https://developers.google.com/gmail/contextual_gadgets#summary_of_steps) the gadget spec must be published on the public internet.